# OS X Mavericks / Squirrel SQL Client / PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: macos, java, postgresql

I have just downloaded and installed the Squirrel SQL client v3.5.0 (as 3.5.1 didn't work for me).

I have also downloaded the PostgreSQL 9.1 jdbc client.

When attempting to add the jdbc client within squirrel I receive an error message of ava.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone have this working on their system and if so any idea why mine doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've used the JDBC4 version of PgJDBC but you're using an old Java version like 1.4.0.

Use a modern Java release, or use the JDBC3 driver that's compiled for older Java runtimes.

**Update**: Major/minor 51.0 is Java 7. So it looks like this JDBC release was incorrectly compiled with Java 7, instead of Java 6 (which is supposed to be used for the JDBC 4 release). Grab the latest driver release, it should be fine; if it isn't, please report the problem with the **exact driver version** and **full stack trace** to http://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/ along with your exact Java version.

I'd be interested in knowing exactly where you got this JDBC driver; any incorrectly built drivers should be removed from circulation.

Comment: `java -versionjava version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)`

Comment: @KayakJim Hmm. At least one JDBC driver release was incorrectly built using Java 7. What driver version are you using *exactly*?

Comment: The file I'm working with is postgresql-9.1-903.jdbc4.jar. If you can advise how I can obtain the driver version I would be happy to get it.